# Populate a tableView doesn't update

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

Here is my problem. I have a table view that is filled depending on the content of an array. Up to now, everything is fine. This array is used to store some maps name coming from a server. I have a refresh button so that when I click on it, it will update the array with the new maps name (`refresh` method).

When I click on the refresh button, the maps array is modified. Either some maps are added or deleted (if a user deleted a map or created a new map for example). However, this situation does not reflect on the screen.

Let's say I have 5 maps (named 1,2,3,4,5). If I delete one (let's say the map 3) and call refresh, the maps array (`mapsModel->mapsNameList`) will contain 4 maps and the content of this array is proper. However, on the iphone screen, I would see, in the table view, (1,2,4,5,5). I don't know why it doesn't remove a row if it is not in the maps array anymore.

I get the same problem if I try to add a map (let's say a map 0), I would get (0,1,2,3,4) and the number 5 would not be there.

**If I restart the application, then all the maps appear properly...**

Here is my code, if some variables name aren't clear of obvious, please let me know !

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int numberOfRows = [[MapsModel sharedMapsModel] numberOfMapsInSection:((UITabBarController*) self.parentViewController).tabBar.selectedItem.tag];

    // Return the number of rows in the section. THIS FUNCTION WORKS
    return numberOfRows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MapsModel* mapsModel = [MapsModel sharedMapsModel];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[[mapsModel->mapsNameList objectAtIndex:((UITabBarController*) self.parentViewController).tabBar.selectedItem.tag] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}


-(void) refresh {
   [[MapsModel sharedMapsModel] populateMapsNameListWithMapState:MAP_STATE_ALL];

    [self updateView];
}

-(void) updateView {
    //Reorder the maps by alphabetical order
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
    MapsModel* mapsModel = [MapsModel sharedMapsModel];

    sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    [[mapsModel->mapsNameList objectAtIndex:self.tabBarItem.tag] sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    //Update the table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the problem, I had a tab bar controller and three table views. However, I tried to use only one view controller for all the three table views... One view controller per table view resolved my problem !

Comment: please post questions only after trying something .

Comment: If the only difference between your tabs is the contents of table view, you can use one view controller and a tableview in it for all of them, only change data source and reload the table when switching between tabs. It should work, there is no need to one view controller and table view for each tab

Comment: @MilKyWaY I tried for 5 hours before posting this question. I did not think it was only this simple thing that would resolve my problem ! Please don't be harsh, people are trying to learn here.

Comment: @AbbasMousavi that's the strangest thing, I did the same code in three different view controllers and now it is working....

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `[[MapsModel sharedMapsModel] numberOfMapsInSection:` returns correct value after update? Your table code has no problem, it seems that you should check your `MapsModel`.
Probably your mapsModel returns wrong values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:`

Comment: do you mean that after update you return 4 in ```- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section``` but your table has 5 rows?

Comment: Exactly. numberOfRows would contain 4 (after one being deleted) but the table would have 5 rows. Basically, the table would keep the first number of rows it is being provided

Comment: I think I know the problem, I have a tab bar controller and I think I have only one tableViewController for the three table views...